# Why is converting to JSON so verbose with Playframework?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

I'm just comparing how you would both serialize and deserialize an object to and from JSON in java.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'john smith'}";

User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
```

With the Playframework and Scala, I have to create these reads and writes mappers and they are very verbose. (see: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonHttp)

Why can't it just "work" like it does with java w/Jackson?

**I have my models, and I want to simply read/write then to JSON.  With Java, I don't have any boilerplate code to write.**

Comment: You're conflating Play Framework with Scala in a way that doesn't make sense.  There are a bunch of other JSON libraries you could use with Scala: http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2015/11/06/a-quick-tour-of-json-libraries-in-scala/  Do you want a Scala answer ("how can I get this to be compact in Scala") or a Play Framework specific answer ("why is Play this way?")

Answer (score 8):

from https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonInception

> We have had a few complaints from some people who think it’s not cool to write a Reads[TheirClass] because usually Java JSON frameworks like Jackson or Gson do it behind the curtain without writing anything.
>   We argued that Play2.1 JSON serializers/deserializers are:
>
> - completely typesafe,
> - fully compiled,
> - nothing was performed using introspection/reflection at runtime.

The `ObjectMapper` in Jackson is none of these things. It relies heavily on reflection, so if you feed your class files through an obfuscator it might completely break. Even if you don't, there is no guarantee at compile time that the class you are trying to deserialize is actually deserializable.

Part of the draw of Scala is that it provides very strong compile-time guarantees. Implicits (e.g. typeclasses like `Reads` and `Writes`) factor into that, though they do come with some boilerplate/overhead.

The Play devs hear your complaint, but it's very unlikely that the `Reads` and `Writes` will go away. Instead, they're trying to make it a bit less verbose by providing a macro that finds code like this:

```
implicit val personReads = Json.reads[Person]
```

and interprets it like this, based on the `Person` constructor:

```
implicit val personReads = (
  (__ \ 'name).read[String] and
  (__ \ 'age).read[Int] and
  (__ \ 'lovesChocolate).read[Boolean]
)(Person)
```